# How to maintain types of values when extracting keys and values from a JavaScript object in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, types

I am using Python. I need to gather the content of js object while maintaining the values' type.

for example I have a js file with the next content

```
const rules = {
    force_update_cache: true,
    country: 'gb',
    override_headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1',
    },
    navigate_opt: {wait_until: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: 60*SEC},
}
```

I want to extract the keys and values of rules while maintaining the original type of the values.

I regexed my way to read only the keys and values without the "const rules {, }".
I tried using ast.literal_eval but it doesn't work propely.

I expect to get evantually a dictionary with the keys, and values with their original type.

string.
number.
integer.
object.
array.
boolean.
null.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: To properly parse JavaScript code, you'll need to use [a JavaScript parser](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+javascript+parser). Regular expressions cannot be used to parse non-regular languages; they can be used for parts of the process, but only parts of it.

Comment: Why not just store the data as json?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - the JavaScript parser looks interesting. I am checking thanks!

Comment: @Reyno - I can't use a json file since the keys must be quoted in json. The database that I use is a js file where the keys are not quoted. Adding quotes each time will be not be practiacal.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which is not the most ideal but it works.

I create a js file with the following content

```
const SEC = 1000
const rules = {
    // force_update_cache: true,
    // country: 'gb',
    // override_headers: {
    //   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1',
    // },
    // navigate_opt: {wait_until: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: 60*SEC},
    // use_browser: true,
    // expect: {
    //   element: {
    //   selector: '.css-2vqe5n.esdkp3p0',
    //   wait_opt: {timeout: 20*SEC},
    //   },
    // },
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(rules));
```

and then on the python file I use

```
import subprocess

def rules_extract(filename):
    result = subprocess.check_output(['node', filename], universal_newlines=True)

    # Save the output into a Python variable
    output_variable = json.dumps(json.loads(result.strip()))

    # Print the output variable
    return output_variable
```

This lets me edit the json file conveniently on the js file without adding double quotes to the key.

My database doesn't have the key with quotes so adding them manually is a pain.

using json.dumps(json.loads(result.strip())) parses it so it will be accepted when I outsource it from python.

Thanks everyone for the help. Hopefully someone else will benefit from this bizarre use case.

Answer (score -1):

> use the vm module in Node.js to execute the JavaScript code and access the resulting object.

```
const vm = require('vm');

const script = `
const rules = {
force_update_cache: true,
country: 'gb',
override_headers: {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) 
AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 
Safari/602.1',
},
navigate_opt: {wait_until: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: 60*SEC},
};

rules;
`;

const sandbox = { SEC: 1 }; // Define any variables needed in the code

const context = vm.createContext(sandbox);
const result = vm.runInContext(script, context);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, 

I am trying to extract the content from my python script. The code you provided is in js.

Comment: Whom are you quoting at the top?

Comment: @user3840170 Hi, sorry I added tags so you'll now who I refer to.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try this

```
const rules = {
  force_update_cache: true,
  country: 'gb',
  override_headers: {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1',
  },
  navigate_opt: {wait_until: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: 60*SEC},
};

// Convert the object to a string
const rulesString = JSON.stringify(rules);

// Remove the surrounding braces to get the object literal
const objectLiteral = rulesString.slice(1, -1);

// Use eval() to parse the object literal
const parsedObject = eval('(' + objectLiteral + ')');

console.log(parsedObject);
```

Comment: Hi, 

I am trying to extract the content from my python script. The code you provided is in js.

Comment: @AdamRashbiIzrailov simply you need something external like json